QGIS 3D map not showing labels
I am trying to get labels to show up in the QGIS 3D map viewer. I can see the label in the viewer, if I don't add the symbol to the 3D view, under layer styling.

However, as soon as I add the symbol to the 3D view, I can no longer see the label

